# Deriving a bell curve

Tags: derivatives

I am trying to see if it possible to derive a bell curve for a profession's annual salary. If I know how many people are part of the profession (such as 30,000 persons) and I know the mean annual salary (such as \$234,000) and that I know that the lowest 10% earn \$143,000, how can I derive a bell curve to find out what the highest 10% earn?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Assuming such a distribution is normal... yeah. Just need to do some z-score manipulations. The z-score you seek is $-1.28.$ Now use the usual transformation $x = \mu + z \sigma$ and solve for the standard deviation.

Comment: I wouldn't assume the distribution of salary is normal. If you have access to all the data I suggest developing a relative frequency histogram or a relative frequency polygon to see if its even appropiate to fit your data with a normal curve. Quantitative variables like "salary" often generate datasets that are skewed right.

Answer (score 1):

**HINTS**

- How many parameters do you need to specify the actual Gaussian curve you will be working with (see [Normal distribution on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution))?
- Can you find one of them directly from the data you cited? (Think of mean annual salary)?
- Can you approximate the other one using the $10\%$ bound you cite?

Now that you know both parameters, specifying the distribution is straight-forward.